# how to correct "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence"

Tags: python, mysql, database, replit

Trying to get the columns of mysql to be displayed on website and this is done on replit ,but getting error saying "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence"

```
def load_jobss_from_db():
 with engine.connect() as conn:
  result=conn.execute(text("select * from jobs"))
  jobs = []
  for row in result.all():
   jobs.append(dict(row))
  return jobs
```